# Confidence region vs Confidence interval?

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

Consider a multiple linear regression experiment. I am estimating 2 of the n parameters. I did this using:

1) A joint confidence *region* for the  two parameters an ellipse.

2) Two separate confidence *intervals* for the two parameters.

and got this plot:

I would like to know when do we have a joint confidence region an (ellipse) actually larger than  the two separate confidence intervals and when is it the other way around so not enclosed in  the rectangle of the two confidence intervals?
[image]